# Why are multiple spaces in html hidden input value treated as one?

Tags: html, input, field, whitespace, prestashop

It is obvious, that consecutive whitespaces are rendered as one space in HTML. But why does this apply to the value attribute of hidden input fields ? And how to overcome this problem ?

E.g. the markup `<input type="hidden" name="var" value="a  b">` will result in the value being `a b` (with only one space).

Note : I'm using PrestaShop.

**Edit:** The problem was the following: Prestashop has an option *Advanced Parameters - Performance - Combine, compress and cache - Minify HTML*, that represents multiple whitespaces as one, even in attribute values. It can be considered a bug, since multiple whitespaces are significatif in html attributes.

Comment: Do you mean when you read the value with JS? When you send it to the server?

Comment: When I send it to the server via POST. I did not try to read the value with JS.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please show how you submit the form, how you receive the data at server-side, and how you display it. My guess is that you just echo it in the HTML, and in HTML whitespaces collapse into a single one (unless specified by [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).

Comment: I look at the request details in Google Chrome, and when I have `<input type="hidden" name="test1" value="a b"><input type="hidden" name="test2" value="a  b">`, the submitted form data is `test1=a+b&test2=a+b`

Comment: Is it a typo that you have only one space for both the value of `test1`and `test2`in your example?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Chrome shows `value="a  b"` in the inspector, and `a++b` in the submitted data.

Comment: After all, I suspect that this is an issue with PrestaShop, and that only one space is making it through. I cannot explain and it looks really weird to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal space (not non breaking space or `&nbsp;`) is `&#32;`, you should be able to add double spaces with it.

[Unicode-Table](http://unicode-table.com)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but have you tried `&nbsp;` instead of a normal space?

Comment: This will allow to send multiple spaces, but a space and a `&nbsp;` are not the same characters.

Comment: You can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to switch it back.